# Media size query for body element

Tags: css, media-queries

Is it possible to make some styling apply when the `body` width < a certain value? So similar to a media query but instead of having that apply when then `html`/screen width is < a certain value I want to do it with the `body` tag.

The context of the problem is I am building a page builder and I emulate what the page would look like on a phone by changing the body width. However the phone styling doesn't apply because its the following:

```
@media (max-width: 414px) {
   ....
}
```

What I need is something like:

```
@body (max-width: 414px) {
   ....
}
```

*The reason why I change the `body` width and not the `html` is because my editor div is fixed so if I shrink the body tag my editor div can still be full screen width whilst the body is not. If I change the html width then the editor width shrinks to whatever the phone screen width is.